# OpenNMS WebUI and SSL

Tags: opennms

I've installed OpenNMS (1.12.8) on CentOS 6.5 but I'm having a tough time getting the Web interface to run under SSL.  I can start OpenNMS with it's default port setting of 8980, but when I attempt to modify the /opt/opennms/etc/opennms.properties file to listen on port 8443, it simply never works.  According to the docs, it should work simply by uncommenting a single line of the config!

I can see port 8980 open via netstat, but I never see 8443.  I can even change 8980 to 80 and it works as expected, so I think that the opennms.properties file is OK.  At this point, I assume that there's something deeper that I'm missing regarding Jetty's configuration and HTTPS.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to enable SSL using the built in Jetty in OpenNMS and it didn't work either. 
Right now I am running Opennms under SSL using **apache**.

What you need to do to achieve it is pretty simple:

First install apache.

Then configure your site's .conf file. Mine looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
ProxyRequests Off    
# Rewrite http to https
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{80} !^443$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R=301,L]

<VirtualHost *:443>
#   General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "/opt/opennms/jetty-webapps/opennms"
<Directory "/opt/opennms/jetty-webapps/opennms">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!ADH

# Set up ssl cerfiticates
SSLCertificateFile "/home/ubuntu/2b0a025bef6e41.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/home/ubuntu/keyFile.key"
SSLCertificateChainFile "/home/ubuntu/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt"
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/ssl_request_log ssl_combined
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

In the configuration file, you need to use your own **DocumentRoot**, **Directory**, as well as the **directory for SSL cerfiticates**.

Then enable ssl module and your site by running,

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo a2ensite your-site.conf
```

Finally restart apache.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```